# Does UNION in PostGIS check for distinct geometries, or only other fields?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, union

I've been getting some funny behaviour from UNION vs. UNION ALL when combining two tables in PostGIS, so just wanted to check:

Does UNION include a check for duplicate **geometries** when determining rows to return, or does it only check other (non-geometric) fields i.e. might UNION (rather than UNION ALL) fail to return a distinct geometry from the second table whose non-geometric fields were identical to a row in the first table?

I checked various bits of PostGIS documentation online but couldn't find the answer. It doesn't help that all searches end up dominated by ST_Union!

Comment: Please add an example of your SQL query. Is your question actually something about "How does UNION in PostgreSQL deal with BLOB fields?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UNION` does; row *equality* is checked on **all** returned columns and their *types* (using a [type resolution sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/typeconv-union-case.html)).

---

A thing to consider:

The implicit `DISTINCT` set operator here can be seen as partially enforced using the `=` operator *defined for the given types*, and for PostGIS `GEOMETRY/GEOGRAPHY` types this means *bitwise equality* - as opposed to *spatial equality*, i.e. `'LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)'` and `'LINESTRING(1 1, 0 0)'` are *spatially* equal (as per `ST_Equals`), but **not** *binary equal* (as per `=`):

```
SELECT ST_Equals('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)'::GEOMETRY, 'LINESTRING(1 1, 0 0)'::GEOMETRY) AS "ST_Equals",
       'LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)'::GEOMETRY = 'LINESTRING(1 1, 0 0)'::GEOMETRY AS "="
;

 ST_Equals | = 
-----------+---
 t         | f
(1 row)
```

The important part is that **no defined SRID** is encoded as `0` in the binary representation of a `GEOMETRY/GEOGRAPHY` type, so

```
SELECT 'SRID=4326;POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY AS geom
UNION
SELECT 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY AS geom
;

                        geom                        
----------------------------------------------------
 0101000020E610000000000000000000000000000000000000
 010100000000000000000000000000000000000000
(2 rows)
```

is considered **not *binary* equal** (as seen in the returned sequence).

In contrast, the actual *geometry type* is always encoded as part of the serialization process, so

```
SELECT 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY(POINT) AS geom
UNION
SELECT 'POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY) AS geom
;

                    geom                    
--------------------------------------------
 010100000000000000000000000000000000000000
(1 row)
```

**is** considered *binary* equal (this example is not 100% correct, as the `GEOMETRY` *typemod* does actually nothing to the internal byte sequence, but it gets the idea across).

Comment: Note that you also may find floating point discrepancies for the **same** *computed geometry* between different systems/OS.

Comment: Thank you very much @geozelot. If I could give this 10 votes, I would!